# create a playbook test.yml that will install apache2 sqlite3 git?

Tags: loops, ansible

```
---
- name: install apache2, sqlite3, git pn remote server
  hosts: host01
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Install list of packages
     action: apt pkg={{item}} state=installed
     with_items:
          - apache2
          - sqlite3
          - git


INVENTORY FILE NAME: myhosts

$cat myhosts

[group1]
host01 ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
```

COMMAND USED: ansible-playbook -i myhosts test.yml

ERROR is below one, I don't know what went wrong someone help me in this.

ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, test.yml
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 7, column 12

```
  - name: Install list of packages
     action: apt pkg={{item}} state=installed
       ^
```

We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

```
    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax Error while loading YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872387/syntax-error-while-loading-yaml)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Register variables in with\_items loop in Ansible playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512443/register-variables-in-with-items-loop-in-ansible-playbook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indendation seems wrong at it should be two spaces character by level so try with something like this regarding indentation issue.

```
---
- name: install apache2, sqlite3, git pn remote server
  hosts: host01
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Install list of packages
    action: apt pkg={{item}} state=installed
    with_items:
      - apache2
      - sqlite3
      - git
```

Comment: Kindly please explain how is your answer different to the one in the duplicate question (marked earlier!).

Comment: Still issue not solved, may be this is something valid Error and we can fix it

Answer (score 2):

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  name: install apache2, sqlite3, git pn remote server
  tasks:
  - name: Install list of packages
    action: apt pkg={{item}} state=installed
    with_items:
      - apache2
      - sqlite3
      - git
```

this works for me...

Comment: kindly consider correcting code format of your answer

Comment: Please do the needful as suggested by @Inder It will be easier to understand for others

Answer (score 0):

Given command as

```
---
- name: install apache2, sqlite3, git pn remote server
  hosts: host01
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Install list of packages
    action: apt pkg={{item}} state=installed
    with_items:
      - apache2
      - sqlite3
      - git
```

below error

> ansible-playbook -i myhosts test.yml -b

PLAY [install apache2, sqlite3, git pn remote server] *************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
fatal: [host01] => SSH Error: ssh: connect to host host01 port 22: Connection refused
    while connecting to 172.17.3.177:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.

TASK: [Install list of packages] **********************************************
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/scrapbook/test.retry

host01                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0